# How can I pop-up window when minimize the application?

Tags: vb.net

Visual Basic Window Form Application problem

Hi, I am using Visual Studio 2010, i am facing a problem that

I need to make a timer function, when the timer end, the application will pop-up out the screen **even the application is minimized**.

I tried to google and use MsgBox but still the application do not pop-up the screen!

Comment: You could first restore the window and then show the message box.. Or another way would be to create a custom form to use as a message box. In that way, you can display it as an independent form, which should pop out. If you want to retain the modal behavior, you will want to make use of the first option.

Comment: I found this thread which may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37165241/6144259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go at this

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.TopMost = True
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    MsgBox("Time to take a break! Yay!!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Breaktime")
    MsgBox("Click OK when you've had a break!", MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Waiting!")
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Me.TopMost = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your hlep!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic but look into:

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximize
```